# Estimating a difference with a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: holder-spaces, stieltjes-integral

I'm having trouble with this problem

> Let $X\in \mathcal{C}^{\alpha}[0,T]$ and $Y\in\mathcal{C}^{\beta}[0,T]$ with $\alpha+\beta>1$. (Here $\mathcal{C}^{\gamma}[0,T]$ is the space of Hölder continuous functions of order $\gamma$ in $[0,T]$). Let $\int_{s}^{t}Y(r)dX(r)$ the integral in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense. Prove that exists a constant $C>0$ such that $$\left|\int_{s}^{t}Y(r)dX(r)-Y(s)(X(t)-X(s))\right|\leq C|t-s|^{\alpha+\beta}.$$

I tried to estimate the difference $\sum_{[u,v]\in\Pi}Y(u)(X(v)-X(u))-Y(s)(X(t)-X(s))=\sum_{[u,v]\in\Pi}(Y(u)-Y(s))(X(v)-X(u))$, where $\Pi$ is a partition of $[s,t]$, but I cannot bound it.

Comment: You know something about X(s) - X(t) because of a-Hölder continuity

Comment: You can bound it by ||X||_a |s-t|^a but if the difference is in absolute value. Using triangle inequality on the expression, the estimation is not good enough

Comment: How are you using the b-Hölder continuity of Y? I see many possible expressions (especially in your integral) involving Y(t)-Y(s).

Comment: |Y(u)-Y(s)|≤||Y||_b|u-s|^b and combining  this with |X(v)-X(u)|≤||X||_a|v-u|^a but bounding |v-u| and |s-u| by |s-t| don't allow me to use a suitable partition with an appropriate norm